# In a 4-card hand consisting of only numbered cards (2 - 10), what is the probability that the sum of red cards is twice the sum of black cards?

Tags: probability

Suppose we draw four cards at random, independently, from a typical perfectly shuffled deck of 52 playing cards. Given that we only have number cards, 2 through 10, what is the probability that sum of the red cards is twice the sum of black cards (sum of the number each card represents). An example that satisfies this condition is {6 spades, 2 hearts, 3 diamond, 7 hearts} since $6 \times 2 = 2 + 3 + 7$.

I have been attempting to count each and every case for some hours now, and it seems extremely tedious. I was at some point inclined to just write a computer program to count the possibilities. Any hints or elegant ideas or guidance is very much appreciated. Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: So you're only drawing from the 36 numbered cards of a standard deck?  And when you say "independently" you mean "with replacement?"

Comment: No. You do not replace the cards. You draw cards in the traditional sense of drawing cards from a deck, meaning once card A is drawn, it cannot be drawn again. Independent means the current set of drawn cards doesn't affect the result of drawing the next card. And yes, you are essentially only drawing from 36 cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the sum of black cards.

$B=2,3$ aren't possible.

$B=4$ either means one black $4$ or two black $2$s.  Three reds that add to $8$ are $(2,2,4), (2,3,3)$.  Two reds that add to $8$ are $(2,6), (3,5), (4,4).$

$B=5$ either means one black $5$ or black $(2, 3)$.  Three reds that add to $10$ are $(2,2,6), (2,3,5), (2,4,4), (3,3,4).$  Two reds that add to $10$ are $(2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5)$.

$B=6$ means one black $6$, or black $(2,4), (3, 3)$.  Three reds that add to $12$ are $(2,2,8), (2,3,7), (2,4,6), (2,5,5), (3,3,6), (3,4,5)$.  Two reds that add to $12$ are $(2,10), (3,9), (4,8), (5,7), (6,6)$.

$B=7$ means one black $7$, or black $(2,5), (3,4)$.  (Black $(2,2,3)$ as well as any other three-card black combinations don't yield anything because there isn't a single red card of $14$ or higher.)  Three reds that add to $14$ are:

$$(2,2,10), (2, 3, 9), (2,4,8), (2,5,7), (2,6,6),\\
(3,3,8), (3,4,7), (3,5,6), (4,4,6), (4,5,5).$$

Two reds that add to $14$ are $(4,10), (5,9), (6,8), (7,7).$

$B=8$ means one black $8$, or black $(2,6), (3,5), (4,4)$.  Three reds that add to $16$ are:

$$(2,4,10), (2, 5, 9), (2,6,8), (2,7,7), (3,3,10),\\
(3,4,9), (3,5,8), (3,6,7), (4,4,8), (4,5,7), (4,6,6), (5,5,6).$$

Two reds that add to $16$ are $(6,10), (7,9), (8,8).$

$B=9$ means one black $9$, or black $(2,7), (3,6), (4,5)$.  Three reds that add to $18$ are:

$$(2,6,10), (2, 7, 9), (2,8,8), (3,5,10), (3,6,9),\\
(3,7,8), (4,4,10), (4,5,9), (4,6,8), (4,7,7), (5,5,8), (5,6,7).$$

Two reds that add to $18$ are $(8,10), (9,9).$

$B=10$ means one black $10$, or black $(2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5)$.  Three reds that add to $20$ are:

$$(2,8,10), (2, 9, 9), (3,7,10), (3,8,9), (4,6,10),\\
(4,7,9), (4,8,8), (5,5,10), (5,6,9), (5,7,8), (6,6,8), (6,7,7).$$

Two reds that add to $20$ are of course $(10,10).$

$B=11$ and higher aren't possible because there must be two black cards, and there aren't two reds that add up to $22$ or higher.

Now, to count these.  For each value of $B$ we consider the one-black, three-red combinations, and the two-black, two-red combinations.  Each one-black case has two combinations.

Each two-black case has four combinations for black cards that are different values, and one combination for black cards that are the same value.  Same for the two-red cases.

Each three-red case has two combinations if two of the cards have the same value, and eight combinations if they're all different.

By my count, the total is $17 + 80 + 145 + 204 + 213 + 204 + 145 = 1008$ combinations out of ${36 \choose 4} = 58905$ possible hands, for a probability of about $1.7\%$.

Comment: Thank you. Your count matches what I have from my program which solved it by brute-force, so it has to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can break this down into cases:

Drawing all one colour = automatic failure. Drawing three black cards is also an automatic failure.

So what if you draw one black card? Then you can only draw a a 4 or greater of spades/clubs, that lowest combination corresponding to (2,3,3) of red. The two-two case will have the most cases, I'm sure, but it's manageable.